# CSS3 animation/transition webkit problems

Tags: css

I'm learning about CSS3 transitions and struggling with the vendor prefixes. This is just for fun but I'd like to know why the circle expands on hover in Firefox as it's meant to but shrinks in Safari and Chrome. Webkit seems to be ignoring the width and height but border and opacity are fine. The animation in the normal state seems fine too.

I tried changing the `.disc:hover` `width`, and tried changing the transition to `width` instead of `all` (which seems to work).. it's just `all` that seems to not be working.

A link to the page:
http://ambigraph.com/sketchbook/expando/

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Expando</title>
<link href="expando.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body ontouchstart="">
  <div class="disc">
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```css
@keyframes expando {
    0% {
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        color:#009;
    }
    100% {
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        color:black;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes expando {
    0% {
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        color:#009;
    }
    100% {
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        color:black;
    }
}
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.disc {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius:300px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:50px double;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation:expando .5s ease infinite alternate;
    animation:expando .5s ease infinite alternate;
}
.disc:hover {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:2px double;
    opacity:0;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it may be an animation bug since the `expando` animation is still applied to the element even while hovered. Each browser deals with it differently.

Clearing the animation seems to fix it.

#### CSS

```
.disc:hover {
    /* ... */
    -webkit-animation:none;
    animation:none;
}
```

Comment: i understand.. as the animation is still applied during the hover, one browser is continuing the animation while one continues it in reverse. Thanks for that tip! Makes sense to clear the animation but i wouldn't have thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to differentiate between transition and animation.

The **keyframe animation** defines the activity that is going on regardless of your input (hover or whatever).

The **transition** defines what happens when you do something.

To examine the differences between the two states to see what is being transitioned. Remove the duplicates.

```
.disc {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius:300px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:50px double;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation:expando .5s ease infinite alternate;
    animation:expando .5s ease infinite alternate;
}
.disc:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    border:2px double;
    opacity:0;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Essentially, the hover makes the element transparent while increasing the size and changing the border. Since it's transparent, the border really doesn't matter.